# How to detect which hooked proc calls into my trampoline?

Tags: delphi, hook

I want to do some profiling on how many times a application calls a function in a dll.
In order to do this I hook each and every exported function in the dll.
E.g. if I want to keep track of calls to `user32.dll` I need to hook 830 calls.

Obviously I don't want to write 830 trampoline functions so I've come up with the following scheme:

Use the following hook function:

```
var
  HookFunctionPtr: pointer = nil;

procedure HookFunction;
asm
  .NOFRAME
  CALL @@test  //5 bytes
@@Start0:
  ret; nop; nop  //3 bytes
  CALL @@test  //5 bytes
@@Start1: //Repeat this 1390 times.
  ret; nop; nop  //3 bytes
  //Examine the return address to see which call was hooked here.
@@Test:
  pop rax
  push rax
  push rcx
  mov rcx, qword ptr [HookFunctionPtr]
  add rcx,5
  sub rax,rcx
  shr rax,3 //divide by 8
  mov rcx,rax
  call HookFunction
  pop rcx
  ret
end;

procedure LogCalledFunction(DllEntry: Cardinal);
....
```

When doing the hooking I simply traverse the dll pe-header to get the address of the exported functions. And add a hook to inside the above function.
Every subsequent hook is 8 bytes higher.

I don't see any other way to tell which dll-entry caused the hooked call.
Is there a better way to do this without repeating the same code snippet hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to dynamically allocate a separate stub for each function, where the stub contains the desired context information (DLL function name/ID, etc) as well as some minimal code to call your real trampoline with an extra parameter that points at the stub's context data.  When you hook a DLL function, you would use the stub as the hook trampoline.  When the stub gets called, it would then call the real trampoline, which will then have access to the context data.

This is similar to the approach used by Delphi's `System.Classes.MakeObjectInstance()` function, which wraps a `TWndMethod` inside of a stub to allow object methods (most notably, the `TWinControl.WndProc()` and `TTimer.WndProc()` methods) to be used as Win32 API callbacks for `CreateWindow/Ex()`/`SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`.  When the stub is called by Windows, the stub calls a helper function (`System.Classes.StdWndProc()`) that then calls the actual object method specified in the stub's `TWndMethod`.

This allows one piece of code to handle any number of object instances.  You need something similar for your situation.

Comment: I can use that option to copy the routine as is and simply copy any number of `call xxx, ret, nop` in front as need dictates.

Comment: I used exactly this technique when adapting the Microsoft Layer for Unicode to Delphi. http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/mslu Look in *MSLU.pas* for examples. To generate all the code, I made extensive use of Delphi's macro feature. (That's also the only time I found that feature useful.)

Comment: I decided to put the repeated statements in an include file with a few ifdefs to determine the number of repetitions (based on a constant). That was the easiest and least error prone way.